# Role for Inactive users

Tags: security, role-hierarchy, roles

In our salesforce instance the roles were cleaned up and as a result some of the inactive user's role were deleted, now those inactive users owned records are not pulled in reports as the owner of records do not have any role assigned. With that said, what is the best way to get those records in reports. Is assigning a general inactive user role to all inactive users a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we had many reports filtering "Opportunities under the role XXX" where XXX is our top-level role, which includes all roles. The intent was to include all opps, but opps owned by Users with a null Role field are excluded! A fix is to clear the role value from that filter, changing it to simply "All Opportunities".